# can you convert the values from a file to hex?

Tags: perl

Is there a way to read the values from two text files as hex and print their sum into a third file?

### Example

#### `sym.txt`

02 01 04 01

#### `sym2.txt`

04 0f 07 09

#### `symout.txt`

06 10 0b 0a

This is what I have tried

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

open my $fh1, '<', 'sym.txt'    or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', 'sym2.txt'   or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'symout.txt' or die $!;

while ( !eof( $fh1 ) and !eof( $fh2 ) ) {

    my $line1 = <$fh1>;
    my $line2 = <$fh2>;

    my @l1 = split /\s+/, $line1;
    my @l2 = split /\s+/, $line2;

    my @newvalues;

    my $i = 0;
    for ( @l1 ) {
        push @newvalues, $_ + $l2[$i];
        $i++;
    }

    print Dumper \@newvalues;

    for ( my $i = 0; $i < @newvalues; $i++ ) {
        $newvalues[$i] = sprintf( '%3x', $newvalues[$i] );
    }

    my $new = join( '', @newvalues );
    
    print $out $new . "\n";
}
```

It prints hex values but not all of them, and it doesn't read the hex from the file but the actual values from the file.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't read the hex values from the files and it return only the first value that is 06...but it returns it as hex because i tested it

Comment: Perl doesn't do addition on hex strings natively. Use `hex` to convert them to decimal and `sprintf "%x",...` to convert decimal back to hex string.

Comment: you mean I should do something like $line1 = hex $a and after do $a=sprintf("%x",$a);?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to what you had, but with less intermediate stuff, and I'm using [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) for list transformations instead of `for` loops.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in1, '<', 'in1.txt') or die $!;
open(my $in2, '<', 'in2.txt') or die $!;
open(my $out, '>', 'out.txt') or die $!;

while (!eof($in1) && !eof($in2)) {
    my @vals1 = split(' ', <$in1>);
    my @vals2 = split(' ', <$in2>);
    my @sums  = map { hex($vals1[$_]) + hex($vals2[$_]) } 0..$#vals1;

    print $out join(' ', map { sprintf('%.2x', $_) } @sums) . "\n";
}

close($in1);
close($in2);
close($out);
```

Comment: This will add together as many numbers as are in the line retrieved from `in1.txt`. If there is a different number in `in2.txt` in the corresponding line, then either values will be discarded or a warning will be printed depending on which line is longer. There's also no point in the `close` calls as you don't handle any exceptions

Comment: `print $out join(' ', map { sprintf('%.2x', $_) } @sums) . "\n"` eugh

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

It's more complex that it could be because it follows your example and caters for records with different numbers of values and defaults any missing elements to zero

I have also allowed for up to three hex digits for each total, because 0xFF + 0xFF is 0x1FE

Note that the correct way to split a string on whitespace is to use a single literal space for the first parameter. `split /\s+/` is wrong

This program expects paths to the two input files as parameters on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $fh1, '<', $ARGV[0];
open my $fh2, '<', $ARGV[1];

open my $fh_out, '>', 'symout.txt' or die $!;

until ( eof $fh1 or eof $fh2 ) {

    my @l1 = map hex, split ' ', <$fh1>;
    my @l2 = map hex, split ' ', <$fh2>;

    my $n = @l2 > @l1 ? @l2 : @l1;

    my @sum = map {
        no warnings 'uninitialized';
        $l1[$_] + $l2[$_];
    } 0 .. $n-1;

    @sum = map { sprintf '%03X', $_ } @sum;

    print { $fh_out } "@sum\n";
}
```

### output

```
006 010 00B 00A
```

### Update

To truncate each sum to eight bits, you should change the assignment to `@sum` to this

```
    my @sum = map {
        no warnings 'uninitialized';
        ( $l1[$_] + $l2[$_] ) & 0xFF;
    } 0 .. $n-1;
```

You can also change the format specifier in the `sprint` to `%02X`, as there will never be any hex values bigger than two digits

Comment: And how about if I wanted to write 0xFE + 0xFD as 0xFC because I would like to have the max value in the output file 0xFF but you can have in the first and second input file 0xFF + 0xFF.

Comment: another question popped into my mind ,how can you take values from a specific line ,for example you have : file 1 "01 02 03 05 0f" and file 2: "01 04 06 03 0f" and i would like the sum of the numbers in a file 3 but only of the middle values" considering the first and last value is the same in file1 and file2

Comment: so it wold be "01 06 09 08 0f" @Borodin

Comment: @Sickofthisschool: Do you mean copy the values that are the same and add those that are different? Or copy columns 1 and 5 and add columns 2, 3 and 4? In any case, this question has grown rather too much and your changes should be posted as a new question. It's not actually hard, if you tried to do this yourself. I would set `@sum` initially to a copy of `@l1` and add in the relevant columns from `@l2`

Comment: I am really sorry to do this but ... I need to ask something again... I used  @sum = map { sprintf '%01X', $_ } @sum; and inputed in file1:0000000F file2:00000000F and the result is "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1e" instead of "0 0 0 0 0 0 1 e" ,i modified the program a bit and i know the problem is in this part of the program ....sorry to ask here but I got no questions left for the next 6 days ...

Comment: @SickOfThisSchool: The 1 in `%01X` is a *minimum* field width. It will use as many characters as it needs to represent the full value, so you get `1E`. To separate the characters like that you need to `split //, sprintf '%08X', $_`. But I don't understand why you got eight fields in your output when there was only field of nine digits in your input. You really need to post a new question and show your code and real input files